# Trying to play multiple audio files one by one with one audio player object. But if I don't initalize it again before playing it gives this error dart

Tags: flutter, dart, audio, media-player

```
E/MediaPlayerNative( 8096): attachNewPlayer called in state 4
D/AudioPlayers( 8096): Unexpected error!
D/AudioPlayers( 8096): java.lang.IllegalStateException
D/AudioPlayers( 8096): at android.media.MediaPlayer._setDataSource(Native Method)
D/AudioPlayers( 8096): at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1301)
D/AudioPlayers( 8096): at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1284)
D/AudioPlayers( 8096): at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1241)
D/AudioPlayers( 8096): at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1218)
D/AudioPlayers( 8096): at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1183)
D/AudioPlayers( 8096): at xyz.luan.audioplayers.source.UrlSource.setForMediaPlayer(UrlSource.kt:16)
D/AudioPlayers( 8096): at xyz.luan.audioplayers.player.MediaPlayerPlayer.setSource(MediaPlayerPlayer.kt:51)
D/AudioPlayers( 8096): at xyz.luan.audioplayers.player.WrappedPlayer.setSource(WrappedPlayer.kt:29)
D/AudioPlayers( 8096): at xyz.luan.audioplayers.AudioplayersPlugin.handler(AudioplayersPlugin.kt:87)
D/AudioPlayers( 8096): at xyz.luan.audioplayers.AudioplayersPlugin.access$handler(AudioplayersPlugin.kt:23)
D/AudioPlayers( 8096): at xyz.luan.audioplayers.AudioplayersPlugin$onAttachedToEngine$1$1.invoke(AudioplayersPlugin.kt:39)
D/AudioPlayers( 8096): at xyz.luan.audioplayers.AudioplayersPlugin$onAttachedToEngine$1$1.invoke(AudioplayersPlugin.kt:39)
D/AudioPlayers( 8096): at xyz.luan.audioplayers.AudioplayersPlugin$safeCall$1.invokeSuspend(AudioplayersPlugin.kt:58)
D/AudioPlayers( 8096): at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
D/AudioPlayers( 8096): at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
D/AudioPlayers( 8096): at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:39)
D/AudioPlayers( 8096): at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:95)
D/AudioPlayers( 8096): at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
D/AudioPlayers( 8096): at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
D/AudioPlayers( 8096): at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
D/AudioPlayers( 8096): at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
E/flutter ( 8096): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(Unexpected error!, null, java.lang.IllegalStateException
E/flutter ( 8096): at android.media.MediaPlayer._setDataSource(Native Method)
E/flutter ( 8096): at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1301)
E/flutter ( 8096): at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1284)
E/flutter ( 8096): at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1241)
E/flutter ( 8096): at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1218)
E/flutter ( 8096): at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1183)
E/flutter ( 8096): at xyz.luan.audioplayers.source.UrlSource.setForMediaPlayer(UrlSource.kt:16)
E/flutter ( 8096): at xyz.luan.audioplayers.player.MediaPlayerPlayer.setSource(MediaPlayerPlayer.kt:51)
E/flutter ( 8096): at xyz.luan.audioplayers.player.WrappedPlayer.setSource(WrappedPlayer.kt:29)
E/flutter ( 8096): at xyz.luan.audioplayers.AudioplayersPlugin.handler(AudioplayersPlugin.kt:87)
E/flutter ( 8096): at xyz.luan.audioplayers.AudioplayersPlugin.access$handler(AudioplayersPlugin.kt:23)
E/flutter ( 8096): at xyz.luan.audioplayers.AudioplayersPlugin$onAttachedToEngine$1$1.invoke(AudioplayersPlugin.kt:39)
E/flutter ( 8096): at xyz.luan.audioplayers.AudioplayersPlugin$onAttachedToEngine$1$1.invoke(AudioplayersPlugin.kt:39)
E/flutter ( 8096): at xyz.luan.audioplayers.AudioplayersPlugin$safeCall$1.invokeSuspend(AudioplayersPlugin.kt:58)
E/flutter ( 8096): at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
E/flutter ( 8096): at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
E/flutter ( 8096): at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:39)
E/flutter ( 8096): at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:95)
E/flutter ( 8096): at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
E/flutter ( 8096): at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
E/flutter ( 8096): at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
E/flutter ( 8096): at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
E/flutter ( 8096): , null)
E/flutter ( 8096): #0 StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:607:7)
E/flutter ( 8096): #1 MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:177:18)
E/flutter ( 8096):
E/flutter ( 8096): #2 AudioPlayer.play (package:audioplayers/src/audioplayer.dart:111:5)
E/flutter ( 8096):
E/flutter ( 8096): #3 AudioBloc._onAudioPicking (package:task4/blocs/audio_bloc/audio_bloc.dart:130:7)
E/flutter ( 8096):
E/flutter ( 8096): #4 Bloc.on..handleEvent (package:bloc/src/bloc.dart:211:13)
```

Comment: If i initalize it again then I can't access it onChange methods in bloc. Because of that I can't access total time and it's remaining time.